# Rspec testing find_or_create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, simplecov

I've checked my simplecov result and I've seen that

```
    record = User.where("fb_id = ? or email = ? ", params[:fb_id], params[:email]).first_or_create do |rows|
      rows.first_name = params[:first_name]
      rows.last_name = params[:first_name]
```

etc(all the variables after do |rows| ) haven't covered.

Any ideas, how could I test this stuff ?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The block will only be called if there are no matches for the `where` clause:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create

**Update**

Your test stubs `User` as follows:

`expect(User).to receive_message_chain(:where, :first_or_create).and_return(user)`

You need a second test where `where` returns an empty result set, instead of a user, in order to verify the behaviour of the lines in the block.

Comment: My first or create method is tested. I need to test variables, that I've described before

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Perhaps you can edit your post to show your tests.

Comment: I've changed first post with screenshot

Comment: That doesn't really help. Please shows the actual test code.

Comment: I've made a small correction to my response. Try `expect(User).to receive(:where).and_return([])`. It may help to look at the implementation of http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create (click on Show Source).

Comment: [] does not implement: first_or_create
[] does not implement: email=
in both cases

Comment: Yes, ignore that, bad advice.

Comment: The way I want to stub returned value is let(:fake_query) { User.where(:id => "asd") }

And then try to expect that object to receive email=, test passes but coverage still the same